# DOM traversing library that doesn't require jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom

Are there any small javascript libraries for just DOM traversing that don't require jQuery?
I've heard of sizzle - is there anything else?

Comment: Sizzle is actually what jQuery uses internally, I think.

Comment: You don't need any libraries to traverse the DOM. Just use plain old JavaScript (POJS). If you have a more specific question about the DOM, that would surely help you a lot more.

Comment: @MattMcDonald: for sure one can traverse DOM with only native methods. But how convenient is that? There is insertBefore but no insertAfter, there is getByClassName - but it's not supported in IE below 9 etc. There is querySelectorAll - but again - "certain other browser" doesn't support it.

Comment: @Stann: Many of those are easily patch-able. `querySelectorAll` should never be used. Once you avoid selectors (using proper markup and context-specific traversal methods), you'll find the DOM a lot friendlier.

Comment: @MattMcDonald: Did I say anywhere that I have troubles traversing DOM manually?  - that's because I don't have this problem. If you can do something - this doesn't necessarily means you should. "patch-able" - yes - and you're creating your mini framework when doing that. And it's completely plausible that someone have done a better job before.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [microjs.com](http://microjs.com/).

> Microjs: Fantastic Micro-Frameworks and Micro-Libraries for Fun and
>   Profit!

Comment: That collection is really nice. Trying to figure out how ender and AMD pattern can work together.